# In Jmeter how to find the response time for 1k/2k concurrent user, and also what should be Ram-Up time for 1k and 2k user

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a requirement like API should be capable of handle 5k Concurrent user in 5 Sec.
How can i test this scenario in jmeter.
For 1k Concurrent user what should the RampUp time to be set in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

5000 for 5 seconds is quite easy to achieve:

1. With normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
2. With [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)

   [image]

With regards to the ramp-up, I can only give you:

- a quote from [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

  > The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

  > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).

  > Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.
- and a piece of advice on ramp-up in general: if you're doing some form of a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(software)) it's a good idea to increase the load **gradually**, this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with the throughput and response time because running 5000 threads for 5 seconds will give you only a basic information on the response time for this workload and you won't be able to tell what is the maximum number of users/requests per second the application can support, when performance starts degrading, etc. So you could consider a load pattern like this:

  [image]

  and look at [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) chart to see the relationship between the number of concurrent users and the application response time

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But i tried with same suggestion and its not helping out. After adding rampup Time to 1 and Duration to 5 .Some failures are reported in jmeter.

Comment: I wanted to add images for reference. But unable to attach image's here.

Comment: There are ~93% of Error are reported. This is the sample result Load time:22627
Connect Time:22627
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2901
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2901
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to karma.reliancenipponlife.com:443 [********************************* ] failed: Connection timed out: connect